# Is it possible to get the function name by using the variable declared inside the function

Tags: javascript, function

Can I get the name of the function using the variable that is present inside the function?

```
function abcd() {
    var temp;
    alert(" name of the function using temp ");
};
```

How do I get the name of the function `'abcd'` using temp?

Comment: Why do you have to use the variable? You can get the function name, but not from the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arguments.callee.name`, like this

```
function abcd() {
    console.log("name of the function using", arguments.callee.name);
};

abcd();
# name of the function using abcd
```

**Note:** `arguments.callee.name` will work only with the functions defined with a name. It will not work with anonymous functions. For example, if you had defined your function, like this

```
var abcd = function () {
    console.log("name of the function using", arguments.callee.name);
};
```

`abcd()` would just print `name of the function using`. Because `arguments.callee.name` would be an empty string in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In "non strict" mode you can use `arguments.callee.name`.

But in general you shouldn't - it's unsafe to assume anything about the variable(s) an object or function is known by from within because there can be more than one, or in the case of an anonymous function no name at all.

Comment: How can a function have more than one name? It can be assigned to multiple variables, but those aren't its name, they're just other ways to refer to it.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that's strictly correct, but for _most_ purposes the variables and the formal name assigned to a function are the same thing.  But if you've already assigned a formal name to a function why do you need it internally (hence its deprecation in ES5 strict mode)